# node js: unable to render json data in the html table(shows blank), but the url shows the data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node js.
I am writing a nodejs application to fetch data from mongoDB and display on the page in a table. But the data is not getting displayed.
Usecase is:
User will navigate to `localhost:8999/` to go to the main page called Queue. Here a link for a page `HealthReport` is present, clicking on which user would navigate to `healthreport.html` where I need to display the data from mongo.
I am able to view the json data in the browser, but displaying it in the required page is not working.
Is there any particular directory structure I need to follow ?
I am using a js file to do that but its not working.
That file is `healthreport-db.js` below:

```
$(function() {  


    var startTime = new Date();
    startTime.setMonth(startTime.getHours() - 6); 

    $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost:8999/healthreport/getHealthReport",
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(data) {

            var latest = data.length - 1;
            var snapShotTime = moment.utc(data[latest].snapShotTime).toDate();
            var nfs = data[latest].nfs;
            var hive = data[latest].hive;
            console.log("db.js hit");

            // Add values to Hive Stats Table
            $("#nfs").text("NFS: "+nfs);
            $("#hive").text("HIVE: "+hive);


        },
        error : function() {
            console.log("failed to get hiveInfo data");
        }
    });
});
```

`healthreport.html` file (where i need to display the parsed json data) in "views" directory:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>HealthReport</title></head>
<body>
Health Report
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="nfs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="hive"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="healthreport-db.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`queue.html` file in "views" directory:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Queue</title></head>
<body>
Queue<br>
<a href="healthreport.html">Health Report</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a main js file called `main_web.js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var collectorConn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongotest3'); 
exports.collectorConn = collectorConn;
var app = express();

var publicOpts = { maxAge: 86400000 }; // Max age of 1 day for static content

// Routes
var route = require('./route.js');
var healthReport = require('./healthReportRoute.js');


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static('public', publicOpts)); //all client source will be in public folder
app.use(express.static('views')); //views folder contains html & ejs files
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);  //render html files as ejs


// Route handlers
app.use('/', route);
app.use('/healthreport', healthReport);


var port = process.env.PORT || 8999;
app.listen(port);
console.log("open your browser to localhost:" + port);

exports.app = app;
```

Then I have a `route.js` that is acting as the router:

```
var express =require('express'); 
var router = express.Router();

/* Home page */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('./queue.html',{title: "Queue"});
    }); 

router.get('/healthreport', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('./healthreport.html',{title: "HealthReport"});
    });

module.exports = router;
```

And then I have a `healthReportRoute.js` that is able to fetch the json data on the web using the url `localhost:8999/healthreport/getHealthReport` :

```
var express =require('express'); //add express
var router = express.Router();
var moment = require('moment'); //add moment

//mongoose schema
var appTableProdSchema = require("./appTableProdSchema.js");

router.get('/getHealthReport', function(req, res) {
    // Return the most recent document
     var records = appTableProdSchema
                   .find()
                   .sort({'_id': -1})
                   .limit(1)
                   .exec(function(err, data) {
                        if (err) return res.sendStatus(500);
                        res.json(data);
                   });
}); 

module.exports = router;
```

The `appTableProdSchema.js` is :

```
var conn = require('./main_web').collectorConn;

module.exports = conn.model('AppTableProd', {
    snapShotTime : String,
    nfs: Array,    
    hive: Array
});
```

I dont know how to get the data into the healthreport.html page.
Please help

Comment: If you pull up http://localhost:8999/healthreport/getHealthReport in the browser can you see the data?

Comment: @Jesse: yes, i am able to. I have written the healthreport-db.js file (above) to parse it, but somehow it seems not to be working or getting triggered. have i placed it in some wrong path?, or something wrong with the code ?

Comment: If you open the dev tools in your browser and look in the Network tab... can you see the request to getHealthReport being made...

If so, what is the status?  If it's 200, was there any other error in the console?

Comment: are you sure you are integrating ejs properly to the express view engine?

Comment: if i am clicking on the "HealthReport" link in the main page, its navigating to healthreport.html, and in the dev tool i can see the following:
Name: healthreport-db.js

Comment: If the healthreport-db.js file path was bad you would see a 404 error in the console or the network tab. The way you have it healthreport-db.js should be in the same directory as healthreport.html.

Comment: Are you importing jQuery?  It's not in your code...

Comment: jQuery? no im not. how to do that ?

Comment: I posted an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making heavy use of the jQuery library but have not imported it.

Every time you have $ in your healthreport-db.js, you are attempting to reference the jQuery library.

You can download the library and include it in your project or you can link directly to the library hosted at one of many cdn's.  Here's the documentation and the code to import from google's cdn:

http://jquery.com/download/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your healthreporter.html would look like this:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>HealthReport</title></head>
<body>
Health Report
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="nfs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="hive"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="healthreport-db.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: added. but still..no result. i wish i could show u the screenshot.

Comment: Are you using chrome?  If so, goto More Tools > Developer Tools.  Open the console tab... are there errors?

Comment: i see 1 error there:
healthreport-db.js:4
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slimScroll is not a function(anonymous function)
@ healthreport-db.js:4i 
@ jquery.min.js:2j.fireWith 
@ jquery.min.js:2n.extend.ready
@ jquery.min.js:2J
@ jquery.min.js:2

Comment: healthreport-db.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slimScroll is not a function(anonymous function) @ healthreport-db.js:4i @ jquery.min.js:2j.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2n.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2J @ jquery.min.js:2

Comment: Looks like there is some code referencing a jQuery plugin called slimScroll.  Do you have other code in healthreport-db.js than what you've pasted?  If you've got some code referencing a jQuery plugin, you'll have to download the plugin and include it just like you did jQuery.  The script tag for the plugin must go after the jQuery script tag.

Comment: i hve downloaded these two and added..trying to run again: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="d3.min.js"></script><script src="dimple.v2.1.6.min.js"></script><script src="healthreport-db.js"></script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107047/discussion-between-jesse-lee-and-aiman).

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I moved the ajax js from a separate file to inline javascript in my html...now im able to fetch data.
but what if i am sending an array of json objects, and i want to parse each element of the array as a json ?

Comment: make the array part of the JSON data.  [{"foo":"foo"},{"bar":"bar"}] would be valid JSON.